# Who had "turbo lasers" first, Star Wars or Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: science-fiction, star-wars, the-force-awakens, battlestar-galactica

Most recently in Star Wars VII, *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, they mention "turbo laser" turrets, but wasn't the idea of turbo lasers in Battlestar Galactica first?

Given that a laser being turbo is far out enough, it would be really odd two fictional universes come up with the same thing, no? So, with an eyebrow already raised, who is the copycat, the one with Lorne Greene..., again?

Comment: Accepted ryan's and upvoted Yorik's answer, so it's even, more or less. .. Also, a look into the script reveals "large turbo-powered laser gun emplacements" in scene description before, so it might be the turret, or the turret's/laser's power supply which is turbo-powered - which might make scientific sense, actually. And note how Lucas' love for cars and engines found a way into his space opera this way. Interesting nerdy stuff...

Comment: maybe neither - google [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turbolaser%2Cturbo+laser%2Cturbo-laser&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cturbolaser%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BTurboLaser%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bturbolaser%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTurbolaser%3B%2Cc0) has "turbolaser" first used in 1976.

Comment: Both are ***wronger than wrong***. Neither Star Wars or BSG use actual lasers. Both are basically ionized gas/plasma.

Comment: @cde Well, while we're being scientific here, plasmas have an annoying tendency to expand at some hundreds/thousands km/sec in free space, making them [prettymuch worthless](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunexotic.php#id--Plasma_Weapons).

Comment: @imallett only if not trapped. Look at light sabers. The plasma is enclosed by a magnetic field.

Comment: You have to look outside movies for this one, the answer is Porsche 911, then Saab 99 and by the late 70s *everything* was "turbo"

Comment: @cde From that link: _"Well, you might ask, what about adding some external forces to prevent this? Sorry. If you use matter, you are basically trying to make an armored shell capable of containing a thermonuclear explosion in its interior, and having it somehow break apart when it hits its target. This is more or less impossible. . . . And if you try to use energy, in the form of a magnetic field or something, you have the same problems. Plus the new problem of somehow making a self-sustaining magnetic ball powerful enough to contain a thermonuclear explosion."_

Comment: @cde - users rarely care about scientific accuracy of terms for products they use. People still use anachronisms like step on the "gas pedal" of an electric car, "dial" a cell phone,  buy LED light bulbs even when the "bulbs" don't look at all like a bulb, tape a TV show on the cable company's virtual DVR, save files to a hard "disk" that's really an SSD with that has no disk at all, etc. Maybe the first weapons were lasers, and people kept calling them that even as they evolved into plasma weapons.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the original movie:

> "We count thirty Rebel ships, Lord Vader, but they're so small they're
>   evading our turbolasers." [―Lieutenant Tanbris, to Darth Vader, during
>   the Battle of Yavin](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html)

Which came out in 1977, while Battlestar Galactica first aired in 1978 (thanks @CodesInChaos).

So Star Wars had it first.

Comment: BSG (the original) was a deliberate attempt to cash in on the sudden sci-fi craze created by Star Wars.  It's not a coincidence that it came out 1 year later.  So it's no surprise that they imitated and in some cases ripped off wholesale many elements of that franchise.

Comment: So they built the Death Star with a point-defense system that was unable to target X-Wings - which was exactly the type of ship that they'd need a point-defense system for? Was that bit of it's design done by the same bloke that left a tunnel leading directly to the ship's core?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - that seems highly unlikely. That someone could notice SW popularity (which would itself take time to become popular), convince studios to give them budget, and than go on to record the show, all within a single year, that honestly sounds impossible to me.

Comment: @Davor: It was more than a year - Star Wars was released in May of 1977, while BSG came out in September of the following year.  Also, the show was done on a relatively low budget (compared to SW anyhow - it *was* expensive for TV, ultimately TOO expensive, which is why it didn't last), and as for getting a budget, TV studios aren't stupid - they could tell that SW was going to be huge pretty early on, and they wanted in on that.  TV also tends to take much less time to film - a week or 2 per episode maybe.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - sure, but don't they record at least one full season before anyone will accept it for broadcast?

Comment: @Davor - No, that's what pilot episodes are for.  Many times the pilot and the show don't even have all of the same cast.  (E.g. Star Trek TOS, Babylon 5)  Shows that aren't green-lit, you generally never even get to see the pilot.  BSG's pilot broadcast on the east coast was actually interrupted by a news broadcast on a Camp David summit.

Comment: The pilot movie for BSG came out Canada, 7 July 1978. 1 year 2 Months production to ship time for a full featured 148 minute movie? Not likely.

Comment: @cde It's fairly well documented that Universal revisited Glen Larson's "Adam's Ark" project (which had a somewhat different plot than Galactica) AFTER the evident success of Star Wars. Also, according to Richard Hatch ( http://www.richardhatch.com/battlestar_galactica/ ) filming took "almost one year", working "six days a week and up to almost 16 hours a day".

Comment: @recognizer filming, not pre-production, or post-production/distribution. They may have changed some stuff during the middle but meh.

Comment: @cde I guess if you can find a mention of "turbolasers" in the original Adam's Ark pitch, then the preproduction period would be relevant.

Comment: @SteveIves - shhh...it happens. Somebody bureaucrat decides "We needs us a Death Star" and they get together lots of "procurement specialists" and "weapons suite interaction experts" and such, and by the time they're done they've managed to create something that can do everything *except* what it was designed to do. I'm sure that somewhere along the line someone said "NOBODY would ever attack our Death Star with little itsy-bitsy fighters! It'd be suicide!". Yeah, Mr. Evil Overlord dude - the problem with that is that nobody mentioned to your opponents that suicide is not an option. Whoops..!

Comment: @SteveIves: The turbolasers were primarily meant to keep capital ships away. And they *did* kill a fair number of X-Wing. The TIEs looked quite capable of handling the rest. That "ventilation shaft", though... ;-D

Answer (score 14):

Star Wars had them first .

http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html

> OFFICER:
>
> We count thirty Rebel ships, Lord 
>   Vader. But they're so small they're 
>   evading our turbo-lasers!
>
> VADER
>
> We'll have to destroy them ship to 
>   ship. Get the crews to their fighters.

Answer (score 11):

The premise of this question is based on a few faulty assumptions.

Turbo has 2 correct definitions, and one odd tacked on thing that almost counts as a 3rd definition.

Definition 1, meaning "big or fast". Much as you can have turbocapitalism (an accelerated/exaggerated form of capitalism), you can have turbolasers. These would presumably have a higher rate of fire than regular lasers. Or the lasers could travel faster. Or just be bigger.

Definition 2: "Drawing power from a turbine." Power generation in the star wars universe, as in ours, almost all comes from a turbine (for real world universe, that is coal, gas, hydro, wind, some solar thermal, fission and fusion. It excludes the most basic of solar thermal, and all solar photovoltaic, as well as rockets. Batteries are often thought of as being a turbineless form of power production, but ultimately they store energy produced by another source, likely a turbo one. There can be chemical energy stored and released, such as in gunpowder, without the need for a turbine.

Half Definition 3: Related to a turbo charger in a car. This is really just definition 2 again, because a turbocharger in a car uses a turbine, and that is where the name comes from.

So under definition one, a turbolaser is just one that fires faster than the competition.

Under definition 2, if it one that draws its power from a turbine.

So that leads us to the question of where non turbo lasers draw their power from. As it turns out, they are produced from directly igniting tibanna gas, which is a very concentrated energy source analogous to gunpowder.

This would lead me to the conclusion that Turbolasers have to be plugged in to some sort of generator (likely fusion in the SW universe), contrasting them to more portable lasers.

Further evidence for this is provided [here](http://www.weaponsofstarwars.com/turbolaser-firepower), indicating that the Death Star superlasers are indeed powered by the reactors, and that they are essentially a scaled up turbolaser.

Interestingly, the US Navy actually has a turbolaser in [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Weapon_System). We as a society are so far away from having an energy production/storage source good enough to allow for laser weapons that aren't turbolasers.

I just realised I should edit in a point here. I dispute the assumption that we can be certain that one stole from other other, because the physical concept of a turbolaser, as well as the name, are not particularly unusual or weird. This, combined with the other answer showing a very short timeframe between the two (presumably indicating that BSG script writing was undertaken, or at least started before Star Wars was released) implies to me the more likely answer is that both came up with this idea independently.

Comment: "The lasers could travel faster", I would have loved to see a faster than light light.

Comment: "So that leads us to the question of where non turbo lasers draw their power from." On which grounds did you discount the other definition? I always understood turbolasers to mean they have a higher firing rate than the non turbo ones.

Comment: This is basically the same discussion as for hoverboards. One can read any manner oftextbooks regarding hovering and boards, but the fact remains: it is *named* a hoverboard. And neither do I need to show that my old Chevy was actually a former star that exploded. And no longer goes. Also, my feet were never in danger of being eaten by my Pumas.

Comment: @ Nobody - they can meet both definitions 1 and 2, and earn their name in 2 different ways. The direction I was going with was that if normal lasers were powered in the same way as turbolasers, then we could discount definition 2. You are right that nothing I posted disproves them being turbo under definition 1.

Comment: @LieRyan: The "lasers" in the Star Wars universe aren't beams of light, at least not in any traditional sense. They all travel significantly slower than the speed of light, hence why you can see them traveling across the screen in the movie. I'm too lazy to look up whether there's any canon explanation, but they could be plasma or some kind of container that holds light in a condensed form (some of which bleeds out, making the bolts visible as they travel).

Comment: I believe in cannon they are plasma. So yes, technically they are not turbolasers because they are not lasers. Mythbusters did some frame by frame to find out the speed, and it was slow enough that they could sort of nearly get out of the way in time when it was fired from ~ 10-20 m away